# R - WAC/FLAC conversions with seewave

Tags: r, wav, flac

I need to convert FLAC files into WAV with R. I am using seewave package.

So I am working with a sample file file.flac.

`test <- wav2flac("file.flac", reverse=TRUE)`

I get the following error command

**Error in wav2flac("file.flac", reverse = TRUE) :
FLAC program was not found.**

According to seewave's CRAN (https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/seewave/seewave.pdf#page=207), I need to install FLAC in my PC. I am unsure how to do that.

Best,

R user

Comment: The CRAN page you referenced has a link to the FLAC site, look at the downloads page there.

Comment: I did that. The problem is I am unsure what to download.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes install it if you have

if you have windows: https://windowsloop.com/install-ffmpeg-windows-10/

if you have ubuntu, linux,etc, on console `sudo apt install ffmpeg`

if you have mac, on terminal `brew install ffmpeg`

Regards